# Rollup full file path for node_modules or bundle each external module in separate dir

Tags: javascript, import, bundle, node-modules, rollup

I'm try to work with this test js-file, I want to compile test ES module for browsers via Rollup.

```js
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

export default function () {
    console.log(uuidv4());
}
```

I made `npm i` for this `package.json`

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "uuid": "^8.3.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@rollup/plugin-node-resolve": "^13.0.4"
  }
}
```

`rollup.config.js`

```js
// rollup.config.js

import nodeResolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';

export default {
    input: ['src/main.js'],
    output: {
        name: 'bundle',
        dir: 'dst',
        format: 'es'
    },
    external: ['uuid'],
    plugins: [ nodeResolve({ browser: true }) ]
};
```

After rollup work I get:

```js
import { v4 } from 'uuid';

function main () {
    console.log(v4());
}

export { main as default };
```

#### #1

Can I get full path to node_modules js-file with my prefix?

For example for lib `uuid` (`node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js`) I want:

```js
// for prefix '/assets/js/lib/'
import { v4 } from '/assets/js/lib/uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js';
```

or may be just node_modules lib-file path:

```js
import { v4 } from 'node_modules/uuid/dist/esm-browser/index.js';
```

#### #2

Can I make es-bundle in **separate dirs** for **each external** module (from package json) that was imported by my js-code?

Answer (score 1):

1. Remove modules from `external` section.
2. Use `preserveModules: true` - [docs](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#outputpreservemodules).